# How to get the final counter values in dictionary on iOS

Tags: ios

I have array of dictionary values and have implemented the counter method for individual array items but had problem with getting the final counter values. it was adding individual counter values.

here is the source code.

```
-(void)getData
{
    [lReportArr removeAllObjects];
    lMetaCount = 0;
    NSMutableArray *lTempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:lMetaArray];
    NSLog(@"Metabolic Array:-%@", lTempArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < [lTempArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *lDict = [lTempArr objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *lTitle = [lDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        //Glucose Low count
        if ([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Glucose reading : Low"].length > 0) 
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Low BG:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        //Glucose High count
        else if ([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Glucose reading : High"].length > 0) 
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High BG:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        //Wrong Dose Cause count
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Low Cause: Wrong Dose"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LG Wrong Dose:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"High Cause: Wrong Dose"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HG Wrong Dose:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        //Symptoms Cause count
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Low Cause: Illness"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LG Illness:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"High Cause: Illness"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HG Symptoms:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        //LG n HG Treatment count
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Treatment: Emergency Room"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Emergency Room:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Treatment: Hospitalization"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hospitalization:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        else if([lTitle rangeOfString:@"Treatment: Extra MD Office"].length > 0)
        {
            lMetaCount++;
            NSString *lCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Extra MD Office:%d",lMetaCount];
            [lDict setValue:lCount forKey:@"metabolicCount"];
        }
        [lReportArr addObject:lDict];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
int c = [[lReportArr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"metabolicCount"];
```

this will give you the final count of metabolicCount value for first object stored in dictionary if it contains metabolicCount key